# string!.trim() - what does this ( ! ) explamation mark do here?

Tags: typescript

What is the role of ! in this javascript equation?

```js
let data = 'hello : world';
data = data!.trim();
```

I tried looking into the internet and wasn't able to find any satisfactory solution. Trying this in local browser return nothing.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !` Chrome console is blasting this

Comment: Where did you find this? It looks invalid.

Comment: This is Typescript syntax. It asserts that `data` won't be undefined or null

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem, this was from typescript, dumb me.